# i got issue in eager load - php laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eager-loading

i got a problem with eager load while fetching data from my model i eager load 3 relations , to understand the problem here is the migration from my model i fetch from it

```
$table->increments('id'); $table->unsignedInteger('order_id'); $table->unsignedInteger('product_item_id'); $table->unsignedInteger('product_id'); $table->integer('days'); $table->foreign('order_id')

        ->references('id')

        ->on('orders')

        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('product_item_id')

        ->references('id')

        ->on('product_items')

        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('product_id')

        ->references('id')

        ->on('products')

        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
```

and here the model contains the relation and eager load attribute

```
protected $with = ['order', 'item', 'product'];

public function item()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ProductItem::class, 'id');
}

public function product()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Product::class, 'id');
}

public function order()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Order::class, 'id');
}
```

when i am try to fetch my data from this model here the response i got "i will ignore un-important attributes from object

```
 Collection {#1478 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => OrderItem {#1071 ▼
      #guarded: []
      #with: array:3 [▼
        0 => "order"
        1 => "item"
        2 => "product"
      ]
      -amount: null
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:7 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "order_id" => 1
        "product_item_id" => 1
        "product_id" => 1
        "days" => 0
        "created_at" => "2018-07-10 08:15:02"
        "updated_at" => "2018-07-10 08:15:02"
      ]
      #original: array:7 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:3 [▼
        "order" => Order {#1166 ▶}
        "item" => ProductItem {#1265 ▶}
        "product" => Product {#1366 ▶}
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
    }
    1 => OrderItem {#1072 ▼
      #guarded: []
      #with: array:3 [▼
        0 => "order"
        1 => "item"
        2 => "product"
      ]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #attributes: array:7 [▼
        "id" => 21
        "order_id" => 1
        "product_item_id" => 15
        "product_id" => 4
        "days" => 0
        "created_at" => "2018-07-10 12:44:32"
        "updated_at" => "2018-07-10 12:44:32"
      ]
      #original: array:7 [▶]
      #relations: array:3 [▼
        "order" => null
        "item" => null
        "product" => null
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

i am sure my foreign keys values are assigned correctly 100%

the problem is .. in first object in response i got my eager load correctly but second object it's return null !! while there is product have id 4 and product_item have id 15 !! anyone can help to know what's going on ?

Comment: I've found that sometimes I need to specify the local key as well, so for `item` it would be `$this->hasOne(ProductItem::class, 'id', 'product_item_id');`

Comment: I think that's because you named the relation differently than the model: if you'd had `productItem()` the relation method then I think everything would work as expected

Comment: all your relationship should be `belongsTo` , like this `$this->belongsTo(ProductItem::class, 'product_item_id');` , `$this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');` and `$this->belongsTo(Order::class, 'order_id');`

Comment: Could you please add sample data and let us know what you're expecting and what you're getting?

Comment: thanks guys for help
@aynber and rkj solutions working correctly